# substrings length

Tags: .net

This is kind of a beginner's question but the code I am looking at is in production and I don't want to break anything.  So, just in case: isn't

```
text.Substring(index, length).Length
```

is equivalent to just `length`?

(Except for the potential ArgumentOutOfRangeException.)

Comment: Don't discount the value of the exception.

Comment: These are not in try.  I guess there is an assumption out of range shall never occur.

Comment: Putting it in a try block would destroy the value.  The assumption is not that it never occurs, it is that it can't cause trouble if it does occur.

Comment: You can always place a very general try which will not cause the value loss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will be exactly the same.

Comment: My fingers are like lightning today :]

Comment: I just got my comment everywhere privilege. Just in time to be late to the party :-)

Comment: I think we've exhausted this subject then.  Thanks for your input.  And the one who was the first is the aswering guy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it to me. I can't see any reason for writing it like that.

Comment: The only explanation I figured for myself is that the author (although an experinced) came from C++ background.  They probably had problems with multibyte encodings and so avoided manual calculations.

Comment: @Nickolodeon - Even in that case it doesn't make any sense. `Substring` and `Length` operate on a number of *characters*, not a number of *bytes*. Multibyte would have no effect here, and I can't see a situation where it would in a similar case in C++ either.

Comment: I just vaguealy remember that string in C++ is really a char[].  char in turn (at least, used to be) a byte.

Comment: I was wondering if the original coder thought that it would return a shorter string if that was all that was left. eg "abcd".Substring(2,4) would return "cd" rather than throw an exception. In that case checking for the length would make sense. I believe that some languages do do that but not .NET. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what that actually means with some numbers:

"My groovy test string".Substring(0, 2).Length == "My".Length = 2

"My groovy test string".Substring(4, 2).Length == "ro" = 2

As you say, if startIndex + Length > length of the string, or startIndex isn't in the string then an ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown

So yes, as all of the potential other cases throw an exception.

My suspicion is the author didn't know that the edge case (when startIndex + length > end of string) throws an exception.

Comment: In our case index is always >=0 and I added a check at the beginning that string isn't empty.